# Assigning a name file ( as variable ) to the src attribute in html element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginning my adventure with the Javascript. I stuck in one part of my code. I would like to change assignations of file name to the src attribute in html element. I create the file name in a external function and then I pass it to the function setting new src attribute. I don't understand why it doesn't work. When I assign an exact file it works. Could someone explain it to me ?
Below is the code:

`index.html`

```
<html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="navContent.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#newFile" onclick="showDescriprion('newFile')">newFile</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </nav>

<p id="demo"></p>

<section class="description">
 <h2 id="nevTitle"></h2>
 <script id="nevDescript" src=none></script>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```

`navContent.js`

```
function showDescriprion(chosenNav){

  var idDescript = document.getElementById("nevDescript");

  document.getElementById("nevTitle").innerHTML=chosenNav;

  idDescript.setAttribute("src", chosenNav.toLowerCase().concat(".js"));

  //checking
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=idDescript.getAttribute("src");
}
```

`newfile.js`

```
document.write(
 <dl>\
  <dt>Uni</dt>\
   <dd>Des</dd>\
 </dl>);
```

The problem is here: `<script id="nevDescript" src=none></script>`. When I write `src="newfile.js"` it works. I want to avoid doing the switch-case. That's why I'm doing the `function showDescriprion(chosenNav)`

Comment: Is there any error on your console when clicking that link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting src of html <script> in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371737/setting-src-of-html-script-in-javascript) OR [Changing “src” attribute of <script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007591/changing-src-attribute-of-script)

Comment: @Pratansyah no, there isn't.

Comment: It looks like setAttribute does not assign filename to src attribute

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is ***adding a new script dynamically***, try searching more information about it. You could start here - https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/25/gotchas-with-dynamically-adding-script-tags-to-html - you find some tips and also an warning that a *document.write* call won't work in this case(also, you forgot to use quotes). You can also look this previous question at [Loading scripts after page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737031/loading-scripts-after-page-load), the answer that @Nicolas Bouvrette and @Johannes H. posted will not require the use of any additional library.