How to add script src dynamically with getElementById?
Go easy on me - I don't spend a lot of time in javascript. :D
I am trying to write a script that will build a JS call based on a URL query, but cannot get the script src to update.
For example, if someone visits https://example.com/page?aid=ABC123, I want to create a script call that would function akin to:
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://example.com/script.js?aid=ABC123'></script>
But I need that call to be dynamically built based on the "aid" variable in the URL.
My "page" code looks like this:
<script type='text/javascript' src='' id='hwContent'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const artid = urlParams.get('aid');
var url = "https://example.com/js.php?aid=";
document.getElementById('hwContent').src = url + artid;
</script>

For the moment while I'm testing, the "script.js" code is just a basic "success!" message using document.write - I haven't even gotten to seeing if the "aid" makes it through to the script file.
If I go direct to the script URL, it works.
If I hard code the script URL into the script src field, it works.
But as soon as I leave the src field empty and rely on getElementById to insert the url into the src field, nothing happens - the area that should display the "success!" message is just blank. Chrome inspector shows no JS errors.

Instead of changing the src of an existing script tag, try creating a new one with document.createElement("script"), setting its src, and appending it to the DOM.

I tried that direction too based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371737/setting-src-of-html-script-in-javascript: That gives me a JS error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')

Just use document.head.appendChild(script) there's no need to search for it by tag name.

Interesting... that worked much better than the method in the other question I used.  I wonder what the difference is; might have to play with it to find out.  Much appreciated!

It might depend on where in the HTML your script code is located. If it's in the <head> then document.getElementsByTagName('head') won't work because the head hasn't been parsed fully yet.

Get artid like you did, create a script tag and add it to document.head:
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const artid = urlParams.get('aid');
var url = "https://example.com/js.php?aid=";
var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
s.setAttribute( 'src', url + artid );
 document.head.appendChild( s );


That did the trick! Thanks so much for the code!

Side note: I also had to add s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript'); to get the data past the CORB blocker.
